# Extensible double angle, etc

Tags: math-mode

I was wondering about an efficient way to generate an inner product symbol like

```
\[
\langle\langle u, v \rangle\rangle
\]
```

(i.e., double angle brackets), or a norm symbol like

```
\[
\lvert\lVert x \rVert\rvert
\]
```

(i.e., triple bars). Of course, the above examples are terrible, no respect for spaces. Is there an efficient way of doing this so that the delimiters are extensible (compatible with `$\left$` and `$\right$`)?

I know of the package *nath*, but it's quite incompatible with amsmath, and generates thousands of errors, so is not an option. I've also tried with "DeclareMathDelimiterX" in *mathmode*, but couldn't get it to work quite as well as I'ld like.

Comment: You can try `\llangle` and `\rrangle` from the `mnsymbol` package for the first one.

Comment: @MartinTapankov, just a remark: for me, the package is `MnSymbol`.

Comment: These are also to be available from the stix package.

Comment: See also answers in: [math mode - How to get double angle bracket without using MnSymbol package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79657/how-to-get-double-angle-bracket-without-using-mnsymbol-package?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 18):

Strangely enough, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) didn't help here. Another great source is [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/), and this has the following answers:

For your first delimiter pair, use `\llangle` and `\rrangle` from the `MnSymbol` package (as observed in Martin's comment above). For the second pair, you can try `\vvvert` from `mathabx`.

Comment: I've been writing an answer of my own, but you beat me to it :-) Also somewhat of an option is `\interleave` from  `stmaryrd`, with the caveat that the spacing around it is all wrong (no left and right versions)

Comment: Sorry, @Martin. You shouldn't have started with a comment `:-)`

Comment: you should it report to Daniel Kirsch. Then he can improve his script, that it finds the `\llangle`

Comment: @Herbert: Done `:-)`

Comment: `MnSymbol` conflicts with the `physics` package :/ How can I just get the `\llangle` and `\rangle` without having everything break?

Answer (score 13):

You might want to try [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) with an appropriate font, since Unicode has ⟪double angles⟫ and ⦀triple bars⦀. So you can write `\left⦀` or `\right⟫`, no need for ugly hacks and the spacing is right. And for extra sugar you can use [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) with it, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innprod[2]{⟪}{⟫}{#1\delimsize|#2}

\begin{document}
$\innprod*{\frac{a}{ξ}}{b}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the aforementionned code]

Answer (score 6):

previous answers for `\llangle` and `\rrangle` are good.

this code for triple verts gets good results, although it's a bit of a hack:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tvsp{\mathchoice{{}\mkern-4.5mu}{{}\mkern-4.5mu}{{}\mkern-2.5mu}{}}
\def\ltrivert{\left|\@tvsp\left|\@tvsp\left|}
\def\rtrivert{\right|\@tvsp\right|\@tvsp\right|}
\makeatother
```

using `\left` and `\right` with `\interleave` might also work well; never tried it,
since we needed these symbols before the `stmaryrd` font was available.