# How to get double angle bracket without using MnSymbol package?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I tried the `\llangle` and `\rrangle` from the [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) package, which is OK. But the package also changed other things which I do not want.

Comment: You may find your answer in one of the following posts (either related/duplicate): [How to use `MnSymbol` along with other packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17370/5764); [How can I use a symbol provided by a package without changing the entire mathematics font?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36006/5764); [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764); [How can I get double angle brackets, i.e. - `<<` `>>`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27582/5764); [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: There is also the stix package that has these.  I don't know if this will  change things you don't want though.

Comment: See also: [math mode - Extensible double angle, etc - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12464/extensible-double-angle-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 25):

The following solution extract the code for `\llangle` and `\rrangle` from package `MnSymbol`. To avoid name clashes `largesymbols` is renamed to `MnLargeSymbols`.
Using the font of `MnSymbol`, `\left` and `\right` are working with `\llangle` and `\rrangle`, because `\left` and `\right` are based on font level features.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnLargeSymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnLargeSymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12
}{}

\let\llangle\@undefined
\let\rrangle\@undefined
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\llangle}{\mathopen}%
                     {MnLargeSymbols}{'164}{MnLargeSymbols}{'164}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rrangle}{\mathclose}%
                     {MnLargeSymbols}{'171}{MnLargeSymbols}{'171}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \llangle x,y\rrangle \]
\[ \left\llangle \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2} \right\rrangle \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @MvG It's just a typo, instead of "operators" "symbols" is meant, see updated answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can build a suitable symbol by taking two ordinary brackets and placing them suitably close together.  I guess your main problem is building symbols that can be used at larger sizes.  Here is a partial solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@brx}
\newcommand{\llangle}[1][]{\savebox{\@brx}{\(\m@th{#1\langle}\)}%
  \mathopen{\copy\@brx\kern-0.5\wd\@brx\usebox{\@brx}}}
\newcommand{\rrangle}[1][]{\savebox{\@brx}{\(\m@th{#1\rangle}\)}%
  \mathclose{\copy\@brx\kern-0.5\wd\@brx\usebox{\@brx}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\( \llangle x \rrangle \)

\begin{displaymath}
  \llangle[\Bigg]{\int_X \nu^2}\rrangle[\Bigg]
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

As the symbol built is not a genuine math delimiter to LaTeX you can not use the `\left/\right` commands or `\big` etc. in the usual way.  So I have instead built commands that taking the size operators `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`,... as an argument.

It works by making a box with one copy of the delimiter (the `\m@th` command ensures that any math surround is cancelled in that process), printing a copy of that box (via `\copy`), backuping by `0.5` times its width and then printing the box again (this last time via `\usebox` to also discard its contents).  You might want to adjust the factor `0.5`.

An alternative choice of spacing is to have a fixed space adjusted by a small amount of the width of the delimiter as in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@brx}
\newcommand{\llangle}[1][]{\savebox{\@brx}{\(\m@th{#1\langle}\)}%
  \mathopen{\copy\@brx\mkern2mu\kern-0.9\wd\@brx\usebox{\@brx}}}
\newcommand{\rrangle}[1][]{\savebox{\@brx}{\(\m@th{#1\rangle}\)}%
  \mathclose{\copy\@brx\mkern2mu\kern-0.9\wd\@brx\usebox{\@brx}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\( \llangle x \rrangle^{\llangle y \rrangle} \)

\begin{displaymath}
  \llangle[\Bigg] \llangle[\bigg] \llangle[\Big] \llangle[\big] A
  \rrangle[\big] \rrangle[\Big] \rrangle[\bigg] \rrangle[\Bigg]
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

The idea of putting the size `\big` etc. in as argument is much like `mathtools` package's treatment of paired delimiters.  It might be that code could be adapted to build commands that would also respect `\left/\right`...

Answer (score 1):

I was unsatisfied with the MmSymbol answer as the glyph differs from the single `\rangle` and `\langle`, so that's not great for consistency and I need both a lot.

So anyway, here is a version based on @andrew-swann's answer, but with automatic scaling. Unfortunately, I was not able to create a version of `\llangle` or `\rrangle` by themselves, so it's limited to a paired delimiter.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\@bra}
\newsavebox{\@brb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\myinnerp[1]{.}{.}{%
  \delimsize\langle%
  \hspace*{0.3mm}\hspace*{0.55mm}\savebox{\@bra}{\(\displaystyle\left\langle\vphantom{#1}\right.\)}\hspace*{-1.035\wd\@bra}%
  \delimsize\langle%
  #1% 
  \delimsize\rangle%
  \hspace*{0.3mm}\hspace*{0.55mm}\savebox{\@brb}{\(\displaystyle\left.\vphantom{#1}\right\rangle\)}\hspace*{-1.035\wd\@brb}%
  \delimsize\rangle
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[
  \myinnerp*{\dfrac{A}{B}} \myinnerp*{\dfrac{a}{b}} \myinnerp*{A^2} \myinnerp*{a}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Again, the spacing is adjustable. The values `-1.035` and `0.55mm` seem to empirically correspond to superimposing the two brackets (don't ask me why), so this is a version with a constant `0.3mm` distance.