# new symbols of <> with larger angle between two arms

Tags: symbols

In below figure we pointed to `<i,j>`

[image]

But we wish to have a special symbol instead of `<>`. In the new symbol we expect that the angle between the two arms are larger than default `<>` i.e., the below symbols

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for `\langle` and `\rangle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( < i, j > \)

\( \langle i,j \rangle \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much but for `\ll i',j'\gg` we cannot use `\langle\langle` or `rangle\rangle`

Comment: I mean the symbol `<< >>`

Comment: Yes, ``\llangle\llangle`` will indeed give a bad result. Some packages provide commands for that. What font are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use `\usepackage{fourier}`

Comment: I think the last part of Sebastiano's answer is very good

Comment: The commands ``\llangle`` and ``\rrangle`` from the ``MnSymbol`` package or the commands ``\lAngle`` and ``\rAngle`` from the ``stix`` package could work, but using either of these packages will influence other symbols as well. Other options to double the ``\langle`` and ``\rangle`` symbols are discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79657/how-to-get-double-angle-bracket-without-using-mnsymbol-package).

Comment: But I did not recognize any change for other things!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want increasing the size of `\langle` or `\rangle`? If the answer is "yes" you can choose the [`scalerel`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/scalerel/scalerel.pdf) package to pag. 7 (for example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
$\stretchto[200]{\langle}{20pt}x,y\stretchto[200]{\rangle}{20pt}$
\end{document}
```

If you want double `\langle` (`\rangle`) you can use `\llangle` or `\rrangle` with `MnSymbol` package.

Comment: Wonderful and intelligent

Comment: @InzoBabaria Naaaaaa. Thank you but it is not true.

Comment: Why you said " but it is not true "!!! it does work for me.

Comment: @InzoBabaria I'm not wonderful and intelligent. I'm just a simple and humble person like so many other people in this world.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps \left\langle ... \right\rangle? That should adjust the size to the contents.