# How to render a "double" ket

Tags: math-mode, braket

I am hoping to render something similar to a *ket* (from the [`braket`](https://ctan.org/pkg/braket?lang=en) package), but where each line is 'doubled'.
For example, something similar to this:

[image]

I would like it to...

- stretch vertically to contain the contents, like `\ket{x}` does
- have subscripts placed below it in the same location that `\ket{x}_n` prescribes.

Here are some insufficient attempts (both using commands from the `braket` package):

- `\ket{\ket{x}}`. It looks like this:

  [image]

  Blegh!
- `\| x \rangle!\rangle`. It looks like the first image in this post, but it *doesn't* scale vertically, and it *doesn't* place subscripts in the right location.

  E.g. `\| \frac{x}{y} \rangle\!\rangle` looks like

  [image]

  and `\| x \rangle!\rangle_y` looks like

  [image]
- `\ket{\!\ket{x}\hspace{-2.7pt}}`. This renders *okay*, but the spacing between the lines varies with the height of the contents.

  [image]

How can I achieve something visually similar to `\|x\rangle!\rangle` but which correctly stretches vertically to contain its contents, and which places subscripts at the same vertical position as `\ket{x}`? This will be used exclusively in math environments.

Comment: Only your 5th (of 7) links are really relevant to my question - the others have solutions which happen to overlap, but are focused on symmetric brackets. Shamefully, the 'duplicate' link used to close this question is straight up wrong - that question is not a duplicate, since it asks about a single ket and doesn't relate in any way to a double ket nor the problems it introduces. The state of this site!

Comment: @AntiEarth -- Some additional corrections would be appreciated in your code: In two places, the `\!` appears as only `!`; and in two images, only one `\rangle` appears.    I hesitate to make these changes since you are more familiar with what you want to see.

Comment: @AntiEarth -- If this is "recognized" notation, it would be a good addition to the `braket` package.  The author's address shown in the documentation is still valid, even if the package is old.  If you write to him, you can say I suggested it, and point to this question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton those are not mistakes in my question; I am demonstrating the behaviour of the candidate solution against a single `ket`. I think the text makes this clear

Comment: @AntiEarth -- I fail to see how the code `\| x \rangle!\rangle_y` would produce the output shown.  With no backslash preceding the exclamation mark, the `!` should appear in the output.  That is what I am trying to point out.  (I'm ignoring that only one `\rangle` appears.)  I don't question that the output isn't what you want.

Answer (score 5):

In `amssymb` and most other packages, ‖ is `\Vert`, which also has the aliases `\lVert` for `\mathopen{Vert}` and `\rVert` for `\mathclose{Vert}`.

Many packages define the ⟫ math symbol as `\rAngle`, and a few as `\rrangle`.  There is similarly a `\lAngle`.  This works with `unicode-math`, or see the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols list for legacy 8-bit packages.  You do not want to use the French-style quotation marks, as those will not properly scale in math mode.

The macros for paired, sized delimiters in `mathtools` are very handy for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % Or stix2, etc.

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Bra}{\lAngle}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Ket}{\lVert}{\rAngle}

\begin{document}
\[ \Bra*{\frac{x^2}{2}} \; \Ket{y} \; \Ket[\big]{x_i^n}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

The `newcomputermodern` package needs LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, but you can substitute your font package of choice.

If you need a three-argument double bra-ket which scales its inner delimiters, there is a code sample in [section 3.6 of the `mathtools` manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#subsection.3.6)

Answer (score 3):

I got some inspiration from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79683/47927) and came up with this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\mstrut}
\newcommand{\bbra}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mstrut}{\(#1\)}%
    \mathinner{\left\langle\kern-0.5\ht\mstrut\left\langle{#1}\right|\mkern-2mu\right|}%
}
\newcommand{\kett}[1]{%
    \sbox{\mstrut}{\(#1\)}%
    \mathinner{\left|\mkern-2mu\left|{#1}\right\rangle\kern-0.5\ht\mstrut\right\rangle}%
}

\begin{document}

$\bbra{x}_n$

$\kett{x}_n$

$\bbra{\frac{x}{y}}_n$

$\kett{\frac{x}{y}}_n$

\end{document}
```

[image]