# How to avoid ligatures of double less equal sign in latex

Tags: fonts, verbatim, typewriter, ligatures

I have lots of C++ code snippets in my article. Just see the following tex content and you'll get what I mean.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}

\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m}{\texttt{{#1}}}

\begin{document}
My code is \code{cout << hello << world;}\\
But I wish it looks like \verb|cout << hello << world;|
\end{document}
```

The different is `«` and `<<`.

How can I avoid ligatures in my `\code` macro.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If you use XeLaTeX, you shouldn't load `fontenc`, but `\usepackage{fontspec}` and you'll see that there are no ligatures by default.

Comment: I am wondering, why you are trying to reinvent the wheel. If you want to typeset code use `\verb` or `\lstinline` and adjust the style (font, color, etc.) instead of implementing the commands yourself

Comment: To make thing more flexible, for example, I can make all code in blue color or in smaller fontsize with `\code`. `\verb` gives me no control.

Comment: You can do all of that and more with [listings](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)

Comment: But I still need a macro to wrap `{\lstinline[language=,basicstyle=balabala]{#1}}`. `lstset` is used for other big code blocks instead of inline ones.

Comment: You can define new sets and aliases and even short versions of macros. Don't get me wrong, I have nothing against wrapping macros for convenience sake, I am just stressing, that it should be the right macros for the job you are intending to do

Comment: yes, now I follow your way with `\lstinline`, I underestimated the power of lstlisting. In fact, I tried it, but used it in a wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `microtype` as shown in [How do I disable ligatures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439651/how-do-i-disable-ligatures):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}% not needed in recent kernels
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding=T1, family=tt*}

\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{m}{\texttt{{#1}}}

\begin{document}
My code is \code{cout << hello << world;}

But I wish it looks like \verb|cout << hello << world;|

Normal ff and ffi ligatures still here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, I tried `\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}` in that webpage but it didn't work at all, why add `family=tt*` works? And what if I remove `encoding=T1`?

Comment: And it seems failed to compile with *xelatex*

Comment: @AsyncCode - The `microtype` package has but very limited capabilities under XeLaTeX. Is switching to LuaLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: Yes, I found I works under LuaLaTeX