# How can I make a scaling matrix norm symbol in overleaf with three bars?

Tags: math-mode

How can I write |||A||| with three bars in equal distances that scale? I read through the exiting entries and none of the solutions worked for me, the closest one was with "vertiii" but this put out bars in different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Using barbara's approach at [Extensible double angle, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12464/extensible-double-angle-etc/12472#12472), which essentially uses triple nested `\left|` and likewise `\right|`, with kerning added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\def\@tvsp{\mathchoice{{}\mkern-4.5mu}{{}\mkern-4.5mu}{{}\mkern-2.5mu}{}}
\def\ltrivert{\left|\@tvsp\left|\@tvsp\left|}
\def\rtrivert{\right|\@tvsp\right|\@tvsp\right|}
\makeatother
\newcommand\tnorm[1]{\ltrivert#1\rtrivert}


\begin{document}

\[
\tnorm{x}  \tnorm{ \frac{A}{B} }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly the same problem occurcs. All three lines are in different sizes...

Comment: @milenteor You haven't provided enough information in your question to even attempt to explain why.

Comment: Hello. What additional information do you wish for? It does not work in overleaf, I do get 3 bars but they cascade in size.

Comment: @milenteor So that I understand, you say that my MWE, run in overleaf, exhibits this behavior you describe? (FYI, I am not a user of Overleaf)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for pointin this out.

Comment: @milenteor That is inexplicable to me, and definitely strange behavior, that three successive `\left|` (essentially) give different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The `mathabx` package defines a `\vvvert` delimiter. Here is a code to use it without loading the package, based  on `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
<-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
<10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\vvvert} {0}{matha}{"7E}{mathx}{"17}%

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\normiii}[1]
{\vvvert}
{\vvvert}
{\ifblank{#1}{\: · \:}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[ \normiii[\Big]{A^k } \qquad \normiii{} \]

\[ \normiii*{∑_{k \geq 0}^∞ A_k} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]